# Determine N Contrasting and Aesthetically pleasing colors

Tags: color, information-graphics

How does one algorithmically calculate a set of N colors that are both contrasting and aesthetically pleasing?  For example, we want to plot an unknown number of lines on a graph that still looks good.

I'm not certain on how to quantify aesthetically pleasing, but not clashing with a given palette might be a starting point (e.g the graph borders and an associated logo are Colors A, B, and C).

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but you might find the answers to this question useful: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7960/clearly-distinguishable-colours-for-scientific-figures/

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a couple of different scheming methods known.

At [Kuler](https://kuler.adobe.com/#create/fromacolor), you can try scheming methods based on analogous colors, monochromatic, triad, complementary, compound and shades. Also check out the wiki page about [color schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_scheme) for more examples (also check out the references for some good book references!)

I think a good way to go is to apply changes to a base color in a consistent matter, e.g. only change one variable (brightness, hue, etc) systematically.