# Choosing color scheme?

Tags: color, color-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-color-scheme-around-col)

Is there any way or tool to choose the best color scheme for a web site?

I'm looking the best colors to use for a corporate web site. I'm just in the beginning of my design process.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11132/determine-n-contrasting-and-aesthetically-pleasing-colors/11133#11133).

Comment: Search this site and you'll find plenty discussions surrounding this topic.

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/colors-in-website-design

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/how-can-i-improve-my-color-selection-skill

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/352/is-there-a-good-resource-or-tool-to-help-build-a-palette-around-colors-i-select

Answer (score 2):

Adobe's Kuler is a good way to hunt for colour schemes and experiment with different palettes.

https://kuler.adobe.com

Unfortunately, Kuler requires Flash. If you have Photoshop or Illustrator, you can use the Kuler panel.

Answer (score 0):

For a corporate site you want to use a limited palate. Suits don't tend to like wild colors. Use toned down colors for most things (your primary site color can be a little punchier, but not super intense generally). Triadic or Split Complementary is probably best, though Analogous can work too.

Answer (score 0):

I love the ability to search palettes on http://www.colourlovers.com/palettes.  This is very useful if you already have a specific color (such as in a logo) and you need suggestions of coordinating colors.