# How to find a maximum set of well separated color-gradients black-to-color?

Tags: color, gradient, resource-recommendations, contrast

I have a question similar to, but hopefully sufficiently different from, this question here: '[Where can I find a large palette / set of contrasting colors for coloring many datasets on a plot?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3682/176054)'

I have the following need: I want to display *n* different things in a single image with a gradient from black-to-color for each, and these things should be distinguishable from each other as best as possible. (For the human eye and on-screen-display.)

This clearly works well for *n=3* with just red, green and blue channel, but I need to extend that concept to an as-high-as-possible number *n*. Is there a reference or publication that deals with that problem?

To illustrate:
I can start out with the **24 well-separated lighter colors** scheme as described in this [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/144516/176054) or [publication](https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v090.c01):
[image: A 24-color palette of well-separated lighter colors]

But while the 24 displayed colors are nicely discernible, their black-to-color gradients are less so:
[image: Black-to-color gradients of the above]

That color scheme is actually not too bad, as one can discern several of those colors to some rather dark shades, but I was wondering if somebody has analyzed the problem more systematically and came up with an optimal solution or algorithm.

Note, that the different colors may appear at any brightness-level and need to remain discernible. i.e. a "dark" variant of color #1 must also be different from a "light" variant of color #2.

As a counter-example: Just naively splitting the HUE value into *n* equidistant parts obviously does a bad job:

[image: 24-HUE-separated gradients]

Comment: THere is no solution to this problem thing is the color variation shrinks when the color gets blacker so there really is no way to do this super efficiently. You need to clamp the values to some range. Color simply is not the solution to your problem.

Comment: @joojaa It's clear, that at a certain level of "too dark" things fall apart, but I'm certain there is *an* optimal solution within the given parameters. The 24color scheme above is already way better than anything I had before, but even that one I would like to "systematically" sort so that picking the 'n-th' color maximizes the overall contrast from the previous (n-1). And I also suspect that a different set of 24colors might be better than that one, but lack the knowledge of how to systematically investigate this.

Comment: No, there really is no way to do this. Thing is  if you find it then you will be awarded a PhD for the explanation. You will have to sacrafice colors. 24 distinctive colors is allready a really big feat. Thing is human color vision is good but it does not really distinguish things in isolation. The problem is that inorder for you to use 24 colors you need to allready use the darkening axis in a way that reduces your space too much.

Comment: Yes, the 24 colors are discernable partly because of their difference in lightness. One would think that your base colors (before darkening) should all have the same lightness?

Comment: @joojaa I'm not insisting on 24 (or bigger) being the solution. But clearly 3 (RGB) colors work, and evidently from above, the first 9 colors of the 24-scheme also "work". I'm certain one or two other of that scheme would work on top of that. So there is *a* solution. Given that the 24colors were mathematically derived from, I suspect one could modify the algorithm to not analyze single colors with each other, but gradients with each other. My primary question was, has anyone systematically studied this yet?

Comment: @Wolff By lightness you mean the L value of the HSL model? The L-values of the colors above do differ (0.539, 0.400, 0.702, 0.563, 0.567,...)

Comment: Imagine the situation that you have points on a line. You need them to be a set distance appart.  This distance is too much for you to fit points but in 2 dimensions you can stagger the points. Ok now you change the rule that they need to be vertical lines. Now staggering nolonger helps as they will hit the sraggered members regardless. Even worse the space is not a rectange but a triangle so even staggeeining does not help as much as it ought to. If you only need 9 colors then use 9 colors.

Comment: @joojaa One can have a metric to compare 2 colors with each other, right? So one should be able to get a list of those metric values for each color of gradient 1 to gradient 2. This list, in turn, could be used to compute a single metric value (average distance, min/max, other statistical property...) . That should allow one to 'rate' and order the gradients, shouldn't it? I know that this is not the same as *finding* the primary colors for the gradients, but being able to numerically evaluate them should be possible, agreed?

Comment: With such an "evaluation" method different sets of colors could be tested and a "solution" be found. It might be hard/impossible to proof that it is the "best" solution - and the solution must not be unique neither - but from a practical perspective one can find a "good" solution - and maybe a better one later.

Comment: You could for example use [chroma.js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/) for such a script. It's easy enough, but exactly *what* to calculate? You are talking about evaluating gradients separately. Then white would be the best base color is my guess, because you'll get the largest distance between colors in the gradient. But you also have to compare all the individual colors from all the gradients to find out if some of them are too close to each other. So you would have to test a set of colors and how to select them? Go through billions of combinations? Perhaps.

Comment: I made [this script](https://jsfiddle.net/MadsWolff/qrmazsbp/47/) for fun. You specify a set of colors and how many steps the gradients have. The script finds the average [DeltaE](http://www.colorwiki.com/wiki/Delta_E:_The_Color_Difference) between all pairs of colors in each gradient and calculates the average. Not surprisingly, it simply finds that the lighter the base color, the more distinguishable the steps are.

Comment: The next step would be to compare all pairs of colors across gradients to find out how good the set is overall. But I don't think the method is sane though. You'll have to find out how to choose palettes to check. A gradient with high average Delta E will hide if another gradient in the set has a intolerable low average Delta E, so you would have to find a way to account for that. A palette could give a good result, but still have a few color pairs which is almost indiscernible. I think it's an evil rabbit hole to venture into.

Comment: There's a recent study: "Rainbows are fantastic," explains lead author Fabio Crameri, "but in the context of displaying scientific, technical, medical or similar such data, it needs to be stopped." This is because the properties of the colors, and the way that the human eye understands them can lead to distortion. More at https://phys.org/news/2020-10-colours-science.html

Comment: Study, which blends psychology, biology and mathematics, discovered that using Riemannian geometry overestimates the perception of large color differences because people perceive a big difference in color to be less than the sum you would get if you added up small differences in color that lie between two widely separated shades. https://phys.org/news/2022-08-math-error-overturns-year-old-perception.html?utm_source=DamnInteresting

Comment: @Stan exactly my point. To OP But see intuitively if color was a 2D plane which it isnt but it gives a bound. There is 2-3 times less lines with sufficient distance from each other at all times. So if you were searching for 12 to 8 colors then you might find sucess. But even then it would ve confusing for humans.

Comment: @Stan thanks for the link, and I'm aware of that. However, my task at hand is not to find a good way to present data, but to optimize an existing one which - for various reasons - cannot be dropped. There are other data visualization options available, but there is a very specific demand for this type of display. (Customer is king) I'm fully aware of the limits, but that shouldn't deter one from optimizing the stuff one is doing. And the current way is just to use RGB and then fractions (R/2 G B) etc. as primary colors. Which is already inferior to the scheme I posted above.

Comment: @Wolff thank you very much. This is pretty much along the lines I was thinking, and as with all such investigations, detail devils emerge when you take a closer look. Hence my original question was if some existing research could be referenced on that problem. If you make your comment into an answer, that would be great and at least upvoted. On the topic: I think "total average" might just be the wrong way to look at the amount of data statistically, as it indeed hides stuff. Also, I believe a "darkness cutoff" needs to be set, or the according values need to be weighted by the darkness.

Comment: @BmyGuest Well you may want to use some k-means clustering to find the colros. Im just saying they will be severely limitted in number of colors. You may want to modify the code and libraries from https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/ where i want hue is one example. It hwowewver does not generally generate 24 colors. so even if you do this its unlikely thet you find more than 8 colors no matter what you do.

Comment: Yes I was just doing some naive scratching in the surface for fun to try to get an idea of the complexity. I'm a graphic designer, not an engineer. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After some fruitful discussions here and elsewhere I've set out to find such a color scheme myself.
> This is all work in progress. I will update as I proceed, but remarks and comments are welcome.

---

## Description of methods

### Comparing two sRGB colors

To compare two colors on my screen I need to compute a distance measure.

I have the colors as `sRGB` values.

I am first converting them into `CIE XYZ` values using the [sRGB->CIE XYZ equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB).

Then I convert them further  then into `CIE L*a*b*` values using the [CIE XYZ -> CIE Lab equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space).

In this format, I can compute the [CIEDE2000 distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIEDE2000) value of the two colors. The higher the value, the better distinguishable are the two colors.

### Comparing two black-to-color gradients

I now want to compare two sRGB colors that each generate a black-to-color gradient.
This gradient is computed in `nGrad` colors. Because too dark colors always will be indistinguishable, I define a *darkness cutoff* below I do no longer care. For this *darkness cutoff* I convert the `sRGB` values into `HSV` values and require a minimum V-value of `Vmin`.

When I now compare two colors that each generate a gradient, I compute the `CIEDE2000` distance from one color of gradient#1 to all other colors of gradient#2 which are above `Vmin` and note the *smallest* of these values, i.e. the least distinguishable pairing. I repeat this for the other colors of the gradient that are above `Vmin`. The overall distance between the two gradients is then defined by the *minimum* value of the individual values.

In essence, I define the *distance between two gradients* as the *minimum-distance of any color-pairing for colors above `Vmin`*.

### Sorting and filtering sets of black-to-color gradients

With the above, I have a way to measure color distances between gradients. In a color set I have `nCol` colors (each generating a gradient), so I compute the distances between all of them. When I say "compute the distance between two colors" I really mean I compute the distance between their respective gradients as described before.

I now sort the list of colors such that the first color is the one with the largest distance to its closest neighbor color. i.e. each color computes the distance to all other colors, and the smallest distance of these measurements is used for the sorting.

Next, I iteratively add the remaining colors, always picking the one which has the largest minimum-distance to the colors already chosen. In essence, I always pick the color which is the most distinguishable from the already chosen one.

On top of that, I define a `DeltaE2000 minimum` value. Any color which isn't at least that distant from its nearest partner gets completely removed.

---

## Testing

As a starting point, I create a somewhat random test set of similar and dissimilar colors that generate gradients. Grey squares indicate colors that fall below my `Vmin = 0.1` threshold and are ignored for evaluation:

[image: Test set]

Applying the method from above and using a filter threshold `DeltaE2000min = 10` gives me the remaining, sorted set below. As I've rotated the image counter-clockwise for easier display, the sorting is from bottom to top:

[image: Test set sorted and filtered]

The result is pretty much as expected, giving me some confidence in the results.
I can now apply the same methods to the **Light-24** color set from my original posting.

Original:
[image: Light 24]

After sorting and filtering:
[image: Light 24 sorted (reduced)]

Note, that only two colors where dropped but that the sorting now allows me to pick N<=22 colors with *maximum discernibly* (as defined above) by starting with the bottom most color and going upwards as required.

### What's next?

As I'm somewhat confident in the methods now, the real *'search for the scheme'* can begin. I haven't completely made up my mind, but I think I will start with a somewhat randomized approach where I iteratively pick a random bright color, test it against the set, and add it if sufficiently different by the defined metric.
When no more color can be found after some break-up criteria, I will sort-filter that list. But it was a long day with lots of new stuff learnt, so this project is a bit postponed for now.

---

## Update

I finally came around finishing this. I did two approaches: One starting with 0 colors and just randomly adding as described above, and two starting with a reasonably 'spread out' color scheme and just adding colors there.

In either case, not surprisingly too harsh restrictions based on "considered dark shades" or "minimum color difference) limit the number of successfully added colors dramatically. In the end, I settled on accepting colors with `HSV V >= 0.2` and a `CIEDE2000 distance of >= 5`. With theses settings, palettes with ~30 colors seem doable.

Below are the three "best" examples I came up so far. One based on the **Light-24** scheme from above, the other based on a palette starting out with RGB fractions, the final one totally random. The schemes are again sorted such that the color distance between columns is biggest on the left and decreases to the right.

[image: Based on Light-24]
**39 colors** based on the Light-24 scheme

**RGB values as CSV**

```
39 colors based on the Light-24 scheme
NAME, R value, G value, B value, minimum distance to all previous colors (gradient)

     Color # 1 , 000 , 181 , 247 , 99.99
     Color # 2 , 246 , 249 , 038 , 43.43
     Color # 3 , 255 , 000 , 146 , 40.61
     Color # 4 , 034 , 255 , 167 , 26.28
     Color # 5 , 106 , 118 , 252 , 22.47
     Color # 6 , 228 , 143 , 114 , 21.33
     Color # 7 , 247 , 255 , 228 , 15.79
     Color # 8 , 214 , 038 , 255 , 13.97
     Color # 9 , 078 , 255 , 000 , 13.39
     Color #10 , 255 , 202 , 255 , 12.81
     Color #11 , 013 , 249 , 255 , 12.13
     Color #12 , 255 , 080 , 091 , 9.79
     Color #13 , 182 , 142 , 000 , 8.95
     Color #14 , 255 , 150 , 022 , 8.56
     Color #15 , 232 , 255 , 121 , 8.09
     Color #16 , 110 , 137 , 156 , 8.05
     Color #17 , 255 , 109 , 224 , 7.87
     Color #18 , 254 , 212 , 196 , 7.23
     Color #19 , 188 , 113 , 150 , 6.67
     Color #20 , 255 , 205 , 126 , 6.53
     Color #21 , 254 , 000 , 206 , 6.33
     Color #22 , 128 , 204 , 000 , 6.31
     Color #23 , 000 , 255 , 217 , 6.19
     Color #24 , 210 , 255 , 192 , 6.17
     Color #25 , 168 , 255 , 109 , 6.16
     Color #26 , 201 , 251 , 229 , 6.03
     Color #27 , 220 , 088 , 125 , 5.93
     Color #28 , 000 , 254 , 053 , 5.60
     Color #29 , 149 , 240 , 255 , 5.59
     Color #30 , 071 , 155 , 085 , 5.56
     Color #31 , 255 , 098 , 061 , 5.52
     Color #32 , 146 , 255 , 234 , 5.45
     Color #33 , 255 , 171 , 187 , 5.28
     Color #34 , 126 , 125 , 205 , 5.11
     Color #35 , 238 , 166 , 251 , 5.09
     Color #36 , 227 , 238 , 158 , 5.05
     Color #37 , 255 , 234 , 149 , 5.03
     Color #38 , 255 , 232 , 255 , 5.02
     Color #39 , 138 , 255 , 197 , 5.01
```

[image: Based on RGB fractions]

**38 colors** based on a scheme using RGB fractions.

```
38 colors based on a scheme using RGB fractions.
NAME, R value, G value, B value, minimum distance to all previous colors (gradient)
     Color # 1 , 128 , 128 , 255 , 99.99
     Color # 2 , 000 , 255 , 000 , 52.03
     Color # 3 , 255 , 128 , 000 , 31.31
     Color # 4 , 000 , 250 , 255 , 24.75
     Color # 5 , 255 , 000 , 128 , 23.13
     Color # 6 , 255 , 255 , 000 , 18.63
     Color # 7 , 255 , 255 , 244 , 15.51
     Color # 8 , 255 , 000 , 255 , 14.15
     Color # 9 , 084 , 168 , 252 , 12.61
     Color #10 , 255 , 000 , 000 , 12.56
     Color #11 , 202 , 255 , 156 , 11.50
     Color #12 , 128 , 000 , 255 , 10.34
     Color #13 , 255 , 143 , 187 , 10.13
     Color #14 , 081 , 255 , 194 , 8.73
     Color #15 , 255 , 186 , 171 , 8.50
     Color #16 , 255 , 206 , 137 , 8.23
     Color #17 , 255 , 128 , 255 , 7.99
     Color #18 , 174 , 255 , 246 , 7.30
     Color #19 , 134 , 255 , 000 , 7.27
     Color #20 , 000 , 000 , 255 , 6.93
     Color #21 , 255 , 255 , 128 , 6.90
     Color #22 , 000 , 128 , 255 , 6.77
     Color #23 , 255 , 190 , 255 , 6.67
     Color #24 , 000 , 255 , 104 , 6.61
     Color #25 , 255 , 167 , 000 , 6.51
     Color #26 , 255 , 230 , 255 , 6.46
     Color #27 , 255 , 128 , 128 , 6.13
     Color #28 , 255 , 142 , 096 , 5.87
     Color #29 , 255 , 206 , 000 , 5.65
     Color #30 , 204 , 255 , 000 , 5.56
     Color #31 , 252 , 084 , 168 , 5.56
     Color #32 , 168 , 084 , 252 , 5.53
     Color #33 , 255 , 085 , 046 , 5.46
     Color #34 , 255 , 252 , 195 , 5.23
     Color #35 , 128 , 255 , 128 , 5.19
     Color #36 , 204 , 255 , 209 , 5.17
     Color #37 , 216 , 229 , 255 , 5.11
     Color #38 , 252 , 168 , 084 , 5.09
```

[image: Based on pure Random]
**32 colors** created by pure random choice

**RGB values as CSV**

```
32 colors created by pure random choice
NAME, R value, G value, B value, minimum distance to all previous colors (gradient)

     Color # 1 , 255 , 255 , 000 , 99.99
     Color # 2 , 255 , 113 , 255 , 47.77
     Color # 3 , 000 , 255 , 255 , 31.95
     Color # 4 , 255 , 072 , 026 , 23.92
     Color # 5 , 000 , 255 , 069 , 20.28
     Color # 6 , 251 , 245 , 255 , 17.57
     Color # 7 , 255 , 150 , 000 , 14.69
     Color # 8 , 199 , 255 , 146 , 10.95
     Color # 9 , 255 , 137 , 176 , 10.68
     Color #10 , 255 , 253 , 205 , 8.20
     Color #11 , 164 , 255 , 000 , 8.10
     Color #12 , 177 , 255 , 255 , 7.69
     Color #13 , 255 , 168 , 161 , 7.38
     Color #14 , 000 , 255 , 201 , 7.37
     Color #15 , 255 , 198 , 113 , 6.79
     Color #16 , 255 , 082 , 112 , 6.05
     Color #17 , 255 , 210 , 180 , 5.99
     Color #18 , 255 , 114 , 038 , 5.97
     Color #19 , 255 , 088 , 185 , 5.95
     Color #20 , 255 , 172 , 255 , 5.72
     Color #21 , 090 , 255 , 000 , 5.68
     Color #22 , 156 , 255 , 172 , 5.64
     Color #23 , 202 , 255 , 217 , 5.56
     Color #24 , 255 , 169 , 109 , 5.51
     Color #25 , 184 , 225 , 255 , 5.50
     Color #26 , 255 , 239 , 137 , 5.46
     Color #27 , 136 , 255 , 223 , 5.34
     Color #28 , 138 , 255 , 108 , 5.27
     Color #29 , 255 , 222 , 255 , 5.22
     Color #30 , 000 , 255 , 131 , 5.21
     Color #31 , 255 , 182 , 000 , 5.17
     Color #32 , 223 , 255 , 106 , 5.10
```

Comment: According to mathematical theory random is the the best strategy if you don't better. Also don't visually evaluate them as swatches next to each other humans are good at this particular thing scatter them around and see of you can pick which color belongs to which color

Answer (score 6):

OK the real answer is don't do it. Its not really possible to do this with very many colors. Finding singular colors that work is a significantly challenging thing, what your asking is even more challenging.

But it is true that there are tools for singular color clusters. You would need to change the way the clustering tools for  [example here](https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/) works (theory explanation [here](https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/theory/) and moderately mature code available [here](https://github.com/medialab/iwanthue)). So if you want to try go for it.

But here is my reasoning why it don't work very well. Lets work on simpler but similar case. image i want to pick distinct points in a 2D space and i want those points to be distinct form each other and as high in the space as possible. Then i would be actually trying to pack circles of some kind.

[image]

**Image 1**: This is what choosing individual distinct colors is conceptually doing. Anything closer than the circle can not be distinguished.

But the problem here is that a gradient is not a point but instead a line. So conceptually in this case points are lines. Staggering lines don't work so well as you get collision with what you have below.

[image]

**Image 2**: This is what choosing gradients to black would look like. Pink areas are problems.

So to be generous to the 3d space you probably can get maybe up to 2-3 levels of staggered points. This then means assuming a 24 colors would fit (a bit more can fit) would predict somewhere around 8-12 colors possible as gradients. The real situation is both better and worse as the color space is tapering towards the bottom but ill leave that to posterity to explain.

Off course i will readily admit this does not prove it can not be done.

Still seems insane expecting a human able to read a 26 dimension image. Just tell your client to think about alternatives. Or at least charge your clients for the research hundreds if not thousands a day with no expectation of success.

But YMMV 6-10 colors probably ok. Hard to say how well would work for color impairment so accessibility would be a serious issue.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your argument with images and more details. I do now better understand. The mental image you have in mind, however, is a bit flawed as I'm not searching for a 'perfect' situation ( "no overlaps" ) but for an "as good as possible" one (minimizing the overlaps in regions that are most critical.) In practice, one won't have just a single color of one gradient (i.e. one intensity) in a region, but a region colored with varying intensities of that color. this will considerably improve the perception. Still "not all colors work equally well" - so I seek the "best set".

Comment: But yes, putting 24+ colors in one map is most likely overkill for all situations. <8 are easy. It's the 8-14 range that is the most probable  real use-case. However, the problem is that many customers want to assign fixed colors to a set of items. (i.e. item1 is always red etc.) and the *set* is bigger than 20. So, ideally they want to assign *n* colors so that when one picks m<n items to map those are nicely distinguished.

Comment: Thus,  there are *n* colors for the customer to select for his "fixed assignment", and I want to make *n* as big as possible while ensuring that using an arbitrary pick of *m<n*  items of that set gives a reasonable gradient map still.

Comment: @BmyGuest im just telling you what the physics and mathematics for this thing is. Physics dont care what you want. If you dont care about overlap then there is no problem just pick whatever.

Comment: Minimizing is not the same as 'don't care'. Neither is the the same as 'has to be zero'. Also, there are clearly colors to be avoided as primary color as well. (those which are part of the gradient of another.) So, essentially I want to get from "User can pick arbitrary color for item-assignment" to "User can pick one of as-many-as-possible/reasonable" options.)

Comment: @BmyGuest no, but if you want them to be distinguishable then they need to have a big enough separation so yes you either care or you dont.

Comment: Agreed. That's where my question came in. How to find the best "cut-off" for that overlap. "0 and not possible" is too harsh and evidently a useless answer. But "arbitrarily large" is equally useless. In between as something reasonable which can be approached by estimates, assumptions and trial & error. My hope was get advice or references for that approach. not more and not less.

Comment: BTW, I've upvoted your answer and appreciated it, but I'm not going to accept it.

Comment: @BmyGuest thats fine. Im just telling you that there is very little middle ground here. You can easily give client n colors out of which 8 is suitable for graduation. Theres not really any good way to maximize the difference. Client can want impossible all they want, but your never going to get any money if your income relys on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139091/discussion-between-bmyguest-and-joojaa).